# what should be the json output of this?

Tags: json

I have class "Company" that having the property "Departments" as list (List).

Having fields:

```
Company : Company_Id,Company_Name,Company_Address,Company_Website.
Department:Department_Id, Department_Name,Company_Id,Department_Contact.
```

here table (in database) Company have one-many relationship with department , and i generate its .dbml file. in asp.net mvc application.

suppose i get serialize this/ used json , then what output should generated there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume it would look something very similar to this:

```
[{"Company_Id":0,"Company_Name":"Foo","Company_Address":"foo","Company_Website":"foo","Department":[{"Department_Id":0,"Department_Name":"foo","Company_Id":0,"Department_Contact":"foo"}]}]
```

Comment: well, i think this should be. but how can i access then "Department" values in jquery ?

Comment: got it. var json =
[{"Company_Id":0,"Company_Name":"Foo","Company_Address":"foo","Company_Website":"foo","Department":[{"Department_Id":0,"Department_Name":"foo","Company_Id":0,"Department_Contact":"foo"}]}];
var cnt =json[0].Department.length;alert(json[0].Department[0].Department_Name);